# Audio plugins. Mapping MIDI to audio files

Tags: c++, audio, vst

I am a reasonably experienced programmer who is pretty inexperienced with C++ and brand new to creating plugins.

Thus far I have looked into http://martinfinke.de/blog/tags/making_audio_plugins.html but it seems incredibly dated, I'm hitting a whole load of compilation issues and don't know where to get the legacy SDKs which would mean I had the exact same set up that the author is using.

I have also looked into JUCE but there isn't a vast amount of resources out there that I can find.

What I am trying to do is create a plugin, VST only for now (will look at compatibility with other vendors later) which simply maps a MIDI input to an audio file which my partner, who is a sound engineer, has already created. We have enough samples for randomising and also various velocities

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend just working your way through the [JUCE Tutorials](https://www.juce.com/tutorials) or watching through the JUCE videos by [The Audio Programmer](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCpKb02FsH4WH4X_2xhIoJ1A/videos) on Youtube to get you started on JUCE. Whilst the first tutorials do not produce audio plugins, the components used within them are crucial 'building blocks' to creating a full plugin.

When you're happy with creating basic GUI elements and how audio can be played/ synthesised within both the Audio App and Audio Plug-In projects, I recommend you try building the smallest part of your plugin you can and, getting that working and slowly building upon it. I suggest starting with how to load an audio file into the buffer (take a look at the looping audio tutorial) as once that is complete it is just a case of using the tutorials again to create and handle the MIDI data.